# How to run minecraft in Debug mode

Tags: java, minecraft

I'm not even sure if you can ask this question here but I have the MCP which decompiles Minecraft code and allows you to edit it using eclipse. As you may know in Eclipse there is a feature called debug mode, whenever I click it, it says in the console.

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Start
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Using incremental CMS is deprecated and will likely be removed in a future release
```

I went to the Start.java file and tried the debug button again but it didn't work
so I was just wondering if you guys know any way around it, The MCP is for 1.7.10 and it's default, not Minecraft Forge. If this is not the right place to ask just ignore it.
`

Comment: make sure that `Start.java`'s folder is defined as a source folder of the Eclipse project into which you imported Minecraft.

Comment: How would you do that? Could you link me to somewhere where it explains it?

Comment: Does it happen only in debug or also when you use Run button?

Comment: And make sure the project is built with no compliation/build problems

Comment: And also make sure that `Start.java`'s package is the default package. That's where Java expects it to be (as the launcher is currently configured).

Comment: The Start.java file is in the default package.

Comment: After building the project, check whether the `Start.class` file is created in the output folder. The output is in `Build Path --> Configure Build Path... --> Default output folder`.

Comment: so are there any issues / problems with the project? Go to the Markers view and check whether there are "Java Problems" related to the project. Any Java error (as opposed to warnings) might prevent the compilation of `Start.java`.

Comment: I'm new so how would i do that?

Answer (score 2):

Making my comment an answer and adding the details you asked for:

Make sure that `Start.java`'s folder is defined as a source folder of the Eclipse project into which you imported Minecraft:

1. Right-click the project in `Project Explorer` view.
2. From the popup menu choose `Build Path` --> `Configure Build Path...`.
3. In the popup dialog, if the `source` tab on the right pane isn't chosen - choose it.
4. If your source folder already appears on the folder list `Source folders on build path` - this isn't the problem. Otherwise -
5. Click `Add Folder...`.
6. In the popup `Source Folder Selection` dialog, select your source folder and click `OK`.
7. Click `OK` in the former dialog.
8. Wait for Eclipse to rebuild your project.
9. Run your main class again and see what happens.